# Error in Eclipse: The method ... from the type ... refers to the missing type Entry

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to use a function that uses the `Entry` object but I am getting the above error message. The function looks like this:

```
public Entry<K,V> insert(K k, V v) throws InvalidKeyException  {
//code here
}
```

I tried importing `java.util.*` but that didn't work.

Could someone please explain to me what this error message is telling me and how to resolve it?

Comment: Is the error only occurring when using Eclipse?

Comment: `import java.util.Map.Entry;`

Comment: I totally don't understand why the question was closed. To me it sounds very reasonable: statement of error message + code fragment + attempted fixes + question "what it means and how to resolve" - exactly what I'd expect on StackOverflow (even the very name of the site hints at that). Also, there's a seemingly valid and comprehensive answer present. I don't even see concrete comments anywhere suggesting to author that something (what?) is "vague/..." and what he should fix.

Comment: In my case it was lack of apropriate _jar_ in build path. I clicked on the _red cross_ and _Eclipse_ suggested _Fix project setup..._, then suggested to add missing jar

Answer (score 5):

It's an *inner class* of `Map`.

Either

```
import java.util.Map.Entry;
```

or

```
public Map.Entry<K,V> insert(K k, V v) throws InvalidKeyException  {
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Trying to import `java.util.*` was on the right track, because you are trying to use a class that isn't in the current namespace.  The reason it didn't work is because `Entry` isn't in the `java.util` package.  In order to import the class, you need to know what package the class is in.

Where did you find the `Entry` class?  If you read `Entry`'s javadoc, then go back and look at the javadoc and see what package it's in.  If you are getting an `Entry` object as the result of a call to another method, look at the javadoc for that method, then follow the link to the `Entry` class, and see where `Entry` is defined.

If you are trying to use some custom `Entry` class, be sure that you've defined it.  If you haven't defined your custom `Entry` class, it won't be defined when you try to use it.